# MS Graph List Mailfolders not returning all the folders

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is anyone else having this issue. I'm using MS Graph to get all the folders in a mailbox using the following URL:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{mailbox}/mailFolders](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bmailbox%7D/mailFolders)

This returns 10 folders. I then use the URL returned in @odata.nextLink to call the API again, repeating this until there are no more. In total I get 39 folders returned.

But, when I look at the mailbox, it has far more than 39 folders. Why is MS Graph not returning them all - they are all under the same parent folder.

Comment: Try the following API call with pagination and see if it works for you. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{mailbox}/mailFolders?$top=10

Comment: That graph MailFolders endpoint only returns folder that have a MessageClass https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/forms/item-types-and-message-classes or subclass of IPM.Note, so things like Contact folder, calendar folders,hidden folders,searchfolders or folders that don't have an ItemClass set or that is set to something custom  don't get returned

Comment: I get the same if I try using ?$top=10 or ?$top=1000, it only returns 39 folders even though there are more. :-(

Comment: I will look at what type of folders they are - they would have been created through Exchange Web Services, maybe the ItemClass isn't set correctly.